# google map infowindow description needs line breaks

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble getting to show linebreaks in the description area of my infowindow. I have tried adding `<br/>` in the description but that does not 
work.

Here is what I have

```
    var bubbleText = '<div class="bubble-container shadow"><div class="img-container"><img src="placeholder1.png" alt="Location image"/></div><div class="info-container"><h2>' + kmlLayerEvent.featureData.name + '</h2><p>' + kmlLayerEvent.featureData.description.split("<br />")[0] + '</p><a href="' + re_result[0] + '" target="_blank">View Brochure</a></div></div>';
```

http://capitalretailproperties.com/map/map.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `<br />` use `<br>`

replace

```
 + kmlLayerEvent.featureData.description.split("<br />")[0] +
```

with

```
 + kmlLayerEvent.featureData.description.split("<br>")[0] +
```

Comment: I saw in console `featureData` you are getting `<br>` not `<br />` that's why split is not working.